# How to send a shake, nudge, or buzz in Lync?

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have tried do some search and also configure it in Lync but it still doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to send someone a shake, nudge, or buzz in Lync?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible... However, If you control+shift+i within a chat session.. you can mark messages with high importance, but this appears to have no effect on the operating system other than an icon change of the chat window within the bottom task bar for that particular users chat session (I don't believe it shakes, nudges, or even buzzes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Lync doesn't support it.